# How to convert the NSString of format (2013-07-25T06:15:33.180-04:00) to NSDate?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How to convert the NSString of format (2013-07-25T06:15:33.180-04:00) to NSDate?

I am trying to convert using the following code

```
NSDateFormatter *rfc3339TimestampFormatterWithTimeZone = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [rfc3339TimestampFormatterWithTimeZone setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [rfc3339TimestampFormatterWithTimeZone setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];

    NSDate *theDate = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![rfc3339TimestampFormatterWithTimeZone getObjectValue:&theDate forString:dateString range:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Date '%@' could not be parsed: %@", dateString, error);
    }
    NSString *strDate = [rfc3339TimestampFormatterWithTimeZone stringFromDate:theDate];
    return strDate;
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this,i hope you'l succeed..

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-07-25T06:15:33.180-04:00"];//chnage symbal here.
    NSLog(@"%@",date);
```